# Facebook Graph API Instagram Data in Python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, instagram

I am trying to use [this](http://facebook-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) Python wrapper to get Instagram data from the Facebook Graph API. My Instagram is connected to Business Manager on Facebook and I am able to connect, but I do not know if it's possible to access [instagram data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/media#insights) through this wrapper. Does anyone know if this is possible, and if not, is there a Python or R wrapper to extract this Instagram data through Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has just released a new version of their graph API (v2.10) that now contains a new [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) that has new permissions that should allow you to read an Instagram user.

1. instagram_basic
2. instagram_manage_comments (optional)
3. instagram_manage_insights (optional)

I hope it helps... Thanks!